# Meteor: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm trying to implement the accounts-ui in a mobile angular-meteor app. I have all the dependencies installed, and I'm trying to setup the Accounts.ui.config with the following code:

```
   import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';

   Accounts.ui.config({
     passwordSignupFields: 'USERNAME_AND_EMAIL'
   });
```

But when I try to run the app, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined
    at meteorInstall.server.auth.js (server/auth.js:4:1)
    at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:153:1)
    at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:82:1)
    at server/publications.js:124:1
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/musiker/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:297:10
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/ubuntu/.meteor/packages/meteor-   tool/.1.4.0.hylsrj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/musiker/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:133:5
```

I thought maybe I need to import accounts-ui for the page, but the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Accounts-ui-config) clearly show importing the account-base.  I also tried importing the accouns-ui and I still got the same error.

Thank!

-Erick

Comment: What packages are you using? Have you added the package account-password and accounts-ui?

Comment: I had all the correct packages, I was just trying to set the config on the server and it needs to be set on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the config on client side code :

```
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';

Accounts.ui.config({
  passwordSignupFields: 'USERNAME_ONLY',
});
```

Have a look [here](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/adding-user-accounts) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Add `accounts` package before using this.

Use this command in the project root to add the package
`meteor add accounts-ui accounts-password`

This should make your code work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to execute `Accounts.ui.config` on the server but this function is only available on the client.

Answer (score 0):

It is Accounts.config.

```
   Accounts.config({
     passwordSignupFields: 'USERNAME_AND_EMAIL'
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error.
First I put the JS into lib/startup/accounts-config.js or lib/accounts-config.js ,it still has error.
But it becomes effective when I put the JS into imports/startup/accounts-config.js. I don't know the reason.